# Meteor Files (ostrio:files) and storagePath for development and production

Tags: file, meteor, path

I use the ostrio:files packages for working with files in Meteor.

therefore i have this settings for the dev environment:

```
const docSettingsDev = {
  storagePath: () => {
    return `${process.env.PWD}/data/documents/`;
  },
  permissions: 0o777,
  parentDirPermissions: 0o777,
  collectionName: "documents",
  allowClientCode: false, // Disallow remove files from Client
  onBeforeUpload(file) {
    // Allow upload files under 10MB, and only in pdf/doc/docx formats

    if (file.size > 50000000) {
      return "Dateien müssen kleiner als 50MB sein.";
    }

    if (!/pdf|doc|docx/i.test(file.extension)) {
      return "Nur PDF, DOC und DOCX Dateien sind erlaubt.";
    }

    return true;

  },
};
```

for the production environment i extend it with:

```
const docSettingsProd = {
  ...docSettingsDev,
  storagePath: "/documents",
  permissions: 0o774,
  parentDirPermissions: 0o774,
};
```

This works fine. The problem i have now is, if i want to restore files from the production environment to my development environment:

as the storagePath is also part of the saved mongo-documents in the mongoDB database, i cannot just copy all content of `prod:/documents/` to `dev:/${process.env.PWD}/data/documents/` as meteor then doesn't recognize the new path. However, when i create a new file on the dev environment the file gets saved in the same path as the restored files, but only the new created files can be fetched by meteor (i assume this has to do with the path-property in the mongo-document for the related document) - the dev environment wants to have the full path (`${process.env.PWD}/data/documents/?`) while the prod environment uses the root path `/documents`.

One then might say: why you don't just use the same path for both: dev and prod use `/documents`? -> because i cannot create a `/documents` folder on my mac machine without permission and i want to have all related parts of the project in my project folder. Is there another possibility to solve this issue? Thank you